# Lines in a list are different lengths

Tags: r

I read in a table from a pdf and it created a list with 9 lines. The lines have different character lengths so I cannot transform it into a dataframe. In line [[1]] "Region" and line [[6]] "Municipal" can both be removed and the the lines will all be 6 characters. The object is stats_lines and it is a list with [8] lines.

[[1]]
[1] "Dodoma" "Region" "450305" "376924" "83.7"   "92.0"   "8.0"

[[2]]
[1] "Kondoa" "55990"  "50197"  "89.7"   "93.0"   "7.0"

[[3]]
[1] "Mpwapwa" "66275"   "59670"   "90.0"    "93.8"    "6.2"

[[4]]
[1] "Kongwa" "61907"  "56497"  "91.3"   "91.7"   "8.3"

[[5]]
[1] "Chamwino" "73807"    "68162"    "92.4"     "94.4"     "5.6"

[[6]]
[1] "Dodoma"    "Municipal" "92978"     "49965"     "53.7"      "73.3"      "26.7"

[[7]]
[1] "Bahi"  "49287" "45884" "93.1"  "100.0" "N/A"

[[8]]
[1] "Chemba" "50061"  "46549"  "93.0"   "98.0"   "2.0"

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `grepl` to detect the items you want to remove and then use `lapply` to iterate over the list, subsetting each element based on the results of `grepl`.

```
lapply(my_list function(x) x[!grepl("Region|Municipal", x)])
[[1]]
[1] "Dodoma" "450305" "376924" "83.7"   "92.0"   "8.0"   

[[2]]
[1] "Kondoa" "55990"  "50197"  "89.7"   "93.0"   "7.0"   
    
[[3]]
[1] "Mpwapwa" "66275"   "59670"   "90.0"    "93.8"    "6.2"    

[[4]]
[1] "Kongwa" "61907"  "56497"  "91.3"   "91.7"   "8.3"   

[[5]]
[1] "Chamwino" "73807"    "68162"    "92.4"     "94.4"     "5.6"     

[[6]] 
[1] "Dodoma" "92978"  "49965"  "53.7"   "73.3"   "26.7"  

[[7]]  
[1] "Bahi"  "49287" "45884" "93.1"  "100.0" "N/A"  

[[8]]
[1] "Chemba" "50061"  "46549"  "93.0"   "98.0"   "2.0"
```

The `str_detect` function from the `stringr` package accomplishes the same outcome with slightly different syntax.

```
library(stringr)
lapply(my_list, function(x) x[!str_detect(x, "Region|Municipal")])
```